# Arduino Pro Micro stray '`' in program

Tags: arduino, hid

My [Arduino Pro Micro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Software-compatibility_only) program gives me the following error. How can I fix this problem?

This is my code:

https://www.joedoestech.com/HackMeThrough/HackMeThroughKeyLogger/keylogger.ino

Error:

```
keylogger:28:34: error: stray '`' in program

     String _getChar(uint8_t key);`

                                  ^

exit status 1

stray '`' in program
```

Comment: fix it remouving `

Answer (score 0):

This line, towards the end of _getChar()

```
  if(shift) return "'";
```

In string literals, the single quote symbol is a special symbol that must be escaped with a backslash, as in:

```
  if(shift) return "\'";
```